# Is it possible to find the time of the last message sent to an SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-sqs

I want to know when the last message was posted to an SQS queue.

Looking at the queue properties (via the CLI or other) I can't see anything appropriate - just the time when the queue *properties* were last modified.

If there's a trick to finding this (without having knowledge of the clients), I'd love to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CloudWatch for this. In AWS Console select CloudWatch -> In left menu select SQS -> Find your queue name and select NumberOfMessagesSent metric. You will see in a graph when was the last message sent.